# Can i change the button of FBconnect

Tags: iphone, button, fbconnect

I am using FBConnect in my app and want to know that can i change that `FBLoginButton`

I think i am using some older version of the FBConnect becaose it is very blurry

There is a method in the button class i can give my own path but  i have worry , will apple accept that change in the API..

```
- (UIImage*)buttonImage {
  if (_session.isConnected) {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"FBConnect.bundle/images/logout.png"];
  } else {
    if (_style == FBLoginButtonStyleNormal) {
      return [UIImage imageNamed:@"FBConnect.bundle/images/login.png"];
    } else if (_style == FBLoginButtonStyleWide) {
      return [UIImage imageNamed:@"FBConnect.bundle/images/login2.png"];
    } else {
      return nil;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The "API" you refer to was created by a company outside of Apple (namely, Facebook). As such, the provisions regarding modifying Apple's source code or using private APIs do not apply.